# Passing arguments using import as to combineReducers

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to understand why `combineReducers` didn't work with version 1 and 2 when I had the following reducers passed down as arguments:

```
import {reducers as summaryReducers} from 'package-A';
import {reducers} from 'package-B';

// Version 1
const store = createStore(combineReducers(summaryReducers, reducers));

// Version 2
const store = createStore(combineReducers({summaryReducers, reducers});
```

The `reducers` is defined as:

```
const reducers = Object.assign({}, { formState: formReducers });
export { reducers };
```

The `summaryReducers` is defined as:

```
const reducers = {popUpManager: popUpManagerReducers};
export { reducers };
```

Is the issue that `import` gets those reducers as objects and we can only pass a single object to `combineReducers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `combineReducers` takes a single object full of reducer functions as its only argument.

In addition, you probably should change how you're exporting those reducer functions.  If you export them inside of objects, you're going to make it more complicated to reference them when you actually call `combineReducers`.  Just export the reducer functions by themselves from `package-a` and `package-b`.

Comment: So, if I only export the function and have something like `export { formReducers };` and `export {popUpManagerReducers}` then can I pass them  as `combineReducers({formReducers, popUpManagerReducers})` or will the `import` again convert them to 2 different objects?

Comment: Yes, that should at least work.  However, from a naming perspective, we recommend _not_ using the word "reducers" in the object keys you pass to `combineReducers`.  Please see the [Structuring Reducers - Using `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) section of the Redux docs for more info on how `combineReducers` uses key names to define the state slices.